# Custom endpoint API REST FRAMEWORK

Tags: python, django, api

Estoy tratando de hacer un endpoint para mostrar la data de diferentes models.

> Webinars,Slide, Academy

```
class Webinars(BaseTitle, Timestamp)

class SlideBanners(models.Model)

class Academy(BaseName, Timestamp)
```

Estos models no tienen relaciones, que recomiendan para crear un endpoint con diferentes models

Serializer:

```
class HomeSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
 slide = SlideBannersSerializer(read_only=True)
 academy = AcademySerializer(read_only=True)
 webinars = WebinarsSerializer(read_only=True)
```

view:

```
class HomeListView(APIView):
 serializer_class = HomeSerializer
 permission_classes = (IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly,)
```

url:

```
    path('home/', views.HomeListView.as_view()),
```

Normalmente hago los serializer con 'ModelSerializer', pero tienen como parametro un model, y necesito hacer el endpoint con tres modelos

Comment: No se logra entender qué es lo que quieres hacer. Trata de ser más específico en lo que preguntas, comenta si tienes un error o qué es lo que no te funciona

Comment: Quiero hacer un endpoint que muestre el contenido de webinars, slide y academy. normalmente uso ModelSerializer, pero este tiene como parametro 'Model' y en este caso necesito pasar contenido de tres modelos, que me recomiendan hacer o leer?

Comment: Pues dado que no sé que quieres hacer, no sé cual esperas que sea la entrada, y menos sé cuál será la salida de lo que quieres hacer. El código que muestras lo veo bien, pero no entiendo cuál es el problema. Así que te recomiendo leer la documentación de [Django Rest Framework](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/)